# C++ Derived Class Error

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I'm trying to become accustomed to classes. Here I've made a base class called `Animal` and a derived class called `Dog`.

I was originally able to to get the base class to work alone, but when I tried adding a derived class, things got messy and I got errors. Here is the code, and if you could let me know what I'm doing wrong, that'd be great!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Animal{
protected:

    int height, weight;
    string name;

public:

    int getHeight() { return height; };
    int getWeight() { return weight; };
    string getName() { return name; };

    Animal();
    Animal(int height, int weight, string name);
};

Animal::Animal(int height, int weight, string name){
    this->height = height;
    this->weight = weight;
    this->name = name;
}


class Dog : public Animal{
private:

    string sound;

public:

    string getSound() { return sound; };
    Dog(int height, string sound);
};

Dog::Dog(int height, string sound){
    this->height = height;
    this->sound = sound;
}

int main()
{
    Animal jeff(12, 50, "Jeff");
    cout << "Height:\t" << jeff.getHeight << endl;
    cout << "Weight:\t" << jeff.getWeight << endl;
    cout << "Name:\t" << jeff.getName << endl << endl;

    Dog chip(10, "Woof");
    cout << "Height:\t" << chip.getHeight() << endl;
    cout << "Sound:\t" << chip.getSound() << endl;
}
```

Comment: What error(s)? Obviously, `jeff.getHeight` in the code you posted is missing the parenthesis `()` required to call the function.

Comment: Opps I missed that. But other than that, I have two linking errors. Unresolved externals is one of them.

Comment: The default constructor for the `Animal` class (i.e., `Animal::Animal()`) is not defined.

Comment: I don't see an implementation of the default constructor of `Animal`.

Comment: Upon removal of `Animal()` I get an error that says 'Animal': no appropriate default constructor available

Comment: @ArchieGertsman, you need to implement the function, not remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The default constructor for the `Animal` class is not defined. You need:

```
Animal::Animal() : height(0), weight(0) // Or any other desired default values
{
}
```

You should also have a virtual destructor on the base class.

```
class Animal
{
public:
    ~Animal() {} // Required for `Animal* a = new Dog(...); delete a;`
                 // deletion via base pointer to work correctly
};
```

---

Edit:

> Upon removal of Animal() I get an error that says 'Animal': no appropriate default constructor available

You need to implement the default constructor (see above). Without it the `int` members will not be initialized and have undefined values.

Comment: @ArchieGertsman Note, I updated my answer to initialize the `int` member variables because otherwise they have undefined values.

Comment: Could I also have set the height and weight when I first declared them?

Comment: @ArchieGertsman Yes, see [Member initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization).